# Implementing "Private Party" with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm working on a project which is implementing its web services using AWS' Lambda and API Gateway. Now, in order to control access to these services, I need to authenticate my users. And it seems the way to do it is using Amazon Cognito User Pools.

The thing is, this project is a private party and not just anyone can sign up. In order for someone to sign up, they'll need a code which I would say, it's going to be emailed to them; e.g. in a link. Once they click on that link, they'll be taken to a page which asks them to authenticate themselves using some public / external identity providers (i.e. Google+, Facebook, etc...). Once they are authenticated, that code is verified and only if it's a valid code, the user should be added to the user pool so from that point forth, they can sign into the system using their emails without any codes.

Could someone please tell me if the scenario is supported by Amazon's Cognito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple approaches you can follow.

**Public Identity providers and External Providers only**

You can customize the authentication challenge to request for a code while login using public and external provider. For more details check the RespondToAuthChallenge section in [Customizing Amazon Cognito User Pool Authentication Flow](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/customizing-your-user-pool-authentication-flow/).

**Support for internal registration in addition to public and external providers.**

Using the Cognito Hosted UI for Signup allowing anyone to SignUp but not activate their account inside your application if they don't provide the code (Need to write your account activator). Also you can configure to remove the user account from Cognito Userpools if the user is inactive for a period.

You can also write your custom Signup page and implement the input of "Code" and do the Signup from a backend using Cognito Userpools Admin SDK. However this can be challenging since you need to do more implementations.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe I need to write Lambda triggers for User Pool Workflows to verify invitation codes, right? In that case, do I need to customize Amazon Cognito User Pool or can I simply use a public / external provider (i.e. Google+ and Facebook)?

Comment: Though I haven't done it before based on my understanding you can still use the inbuilt features with Hosted UI and write the Lambda trigger for public / external providers.